# Please suggest how to debug

Tags: javascript, object, debugging

I am trying to complete the "Map the Debris" freecodecamp challenge https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/map-the-debris, and I think I've gotten it.  It works from my PC's code editor, but when I copy/paste into the website area the conditions don't satisfy.

How do I best debug this?

My code is

```
function orbitalPeriod(arr) {
  let newArr = [];

  function orbSecCalc(avgAlt) {
    const gm = 398600.4418;
    const radiusEarth = 6367.4447;
    let toBeRooted = (avgAlt + radiusEarth) ** 3 / gm;
    let answer = Math.sqrt(toBeRooted) * 2 * Math.PI;
    return answer.toFixed(0);
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let orbSecs = orbSecCalc(arr[i].avgAlt);
    newArr.push({ name: arr[i].name, orbitalPeriod: orbSecs });
  }
  return newArr;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean _"debug"_. Your browser dev-tools include a JavaScript debugger which you can use to set breakpoints and step through your code. See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to parse to int the orbSec variable

Just replace this line:

```
newArr.push({ name: arr[i].name, orbitalPeriod: orbSecs });
```

For this line

```
newArr.push({ name: arr[i].name, orbitalPeriod: parseInt(orbSecs) });
```

Comment: Sorry, the explanation is because you are using the function toFixed in your aux function who convert an int to string (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tofixed.asp)

Comment: OK I understand.  I now understand that toFixed converted into a string. Thank you.